# Why can't I create an Azure Storage in a specific region?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

My Azure Website is hosted in North Central US and when I try to create an Azure Storage in North Central US the subscription I want to use disappears (other subscriptions are still showing). Selecting East US allows me to select the right subscription.

Why?

Answer (score 6):

See the 3rd paragraph on the Windows Azure service dashboard page at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/.

> North Central US and South Central US regions are no longer accepting Compute or Storage deployments for new customers. Existing customers as of June 24th (for North Central US) and May 23rd (for South Central US) are not impacted. All other services remain available for deployment in those two regions. Two new regions, "West US" and "East US", are now available to all customers with the full range of Windows Azure Services, except for the Caching service.

Comment: We've been in that region for almost 3 months. We just got the "Trial is about to expire" notice

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you perform the subscription of the site, the regions are those with available  storage and processing. Once a host of subscription has not capacity, is not listed as available subscription region.